# Vuejs + webpack: npm run build slow

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I'm learning webpack and Vuejs. I've followed the simple instructions at https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/ and that works.

However, when I run `npm run build` to make a production version it takes 12 seconds! I don't understand why this minute demo single-page, no function app that is only 115kB in its entirety takes this long to build.

I've read in various places about excluding `node_modules` from webpack configs, and I can't see that in `vue-cli`'s webpack template - is it trying to minify, lint etc. all the library code or something?

I realise this is very much a noob question, so please be kind to me!

Comment: Yes it does a lot of things

Comment: You can disable source map and you should see it builds much faster

Comment: @CodinCat - sure, that worked for me. Builds were timing out on DO, 512 MB RAM.

Comment: Was getting an error close to [what is described here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4008)

Answer (score 5):

As it was pointed out in the comments by [@CodinCat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2739078/codincat), this is because builds are memory intensive.

They will be slow if you have enough RAM or they will exit with [error code 137](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/4008) if you don't have enough RAM, e.g. running on a small VPS, *Droplet*, etc.

To optimize these builds, you can change the following line in the `build/webpack.prod.conf.js`, `sourceMap: false` (was line `38` in my case), since *sourcemaps* are memory intensive:

```
new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
  compress: {
    warnings: false
  },
  sourceMap: false // changed from `true`
}),
```

Comment: Disabling sourceMaps on vue-cli-service 4.5 didn't reduce the build time so much for me. ([`vue.config.js productionSourceMap`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#productionsourcemap) key)

Answer (score 1):

The source maps creation can take a long time and it grows obviously with source code. So for a simple application you will gain probably few seconds but on a big application with several libraries it can takes several minutes.

As an addition to @ProfNandaa, you can have a VueJs approach by adding the following parameter in vue.config.js :

```
productionSourceMap: false
```

Reference to the VueJs 2 doc : https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#productionsourcemap

Please note that keeping source maps even in production enables you to debug the application (using dev tools browser) and has not impact with application execution.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I used **ts-loader**. The time reduced fromo 15 minutes to 5 seconds after adding transpileOnly: true